# Rundeck 3.4.5 - Run Job Later stop working

Tags: jobs, schedule, rundeck

We're using Rundeck *.war version.  After upgrade to 3.4.5, the "Run Job Now" stop working.  The job got execute immediately after I click "Schedule Job".  Anyone experience this?  Any ideas what may have cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, it seems to be an opened issue on the project : https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/7339. The last message of this thread suggest to downgrade to 3.4.4 as long as it is not resolved if you really need it.